# html and css placing a non-fixed div between two fixed divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a website with 4 main divs (more to come later), 3 of which are fixed, so they dont move when i scroll, and one of them is not fixed. i've been going at it for around 6 hours and 30 minutes straight, googled for possible answers, checked youtube and spent atleast 2 hours looking at stackoverflow posts, none of which really pointed me in the right direction.

design im looking to get:

[design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bFoU.jpg)

source (html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="menu">
        <a href="#"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="contact"></div>

    <div class="upper"></div>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="paragraph"></div>
        <div class="paragraph"></div>
        <div class="paragraph"></div>
        <div class="paragraph"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

source (css):

```
/**/
html,body{
    height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: url("background.jpg");
}

div {
    margin: 0px;
}

.menu {
  background-color:lightgray;
  color:black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  top:200px;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position:fixed;
}

.contact {
  background-color:lightgray;
  color:black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 200px;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position:fixed;
}

.upper {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}

.main {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top:200px;
    height: 200vh;
    left: ;
}

.paragraph {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
}
```

i tried changing the width of the .main div, but regardless of what i try the div either goes under the .contact or .menu div

the .paragraph divs go into to the .main div, to hold some text and images once the .main div is properly positioned. the sizes of the divs in my source arent completely like they are in my design yet cus i kept trying thing to maybe solve my problem.

the .js file is currently still empty so i didnt post any source of it.

Any help is welcome: links; sources; comments; if you know something that might point me into the right direction, please post it!

edit: i tried using a wrapper, but that didnt work out too wel for me, i probably did something wrong, i posted the source that looks the most like my design when i open in in browser.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zt1Lyaop/

Comment: Hmm... Since there is HTML5, it's really better to use <header> and <aside>. And since you are new to stackoverflow (welcome, btw), You have to understand that you will get way more help by adding a JSFiddle.

Comment: ah, thanks! ill add one right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ignored your existing code and made a new, HTML5 and responsive way of creating such a layout. I hope this helps you in understanding this concept better
http://jsfiddle.net/7k9vhk4r/2/

The key is using `fixed` and `relative` positioning, together with creating offsets based on percentages.

Comment: this is indeed much better, and also suits my needs perfectly, thank you.

Comment: actually, in this case, how do i center the text in the header both vertically, and horizontally?

Comment: This could be done with flexbox. I can make an example for you in an hour (in a bus right now haha).

Comment: that would be amazing! also, i have one last question: when i type in one of the <aside></aside> areas, and the text becomes too big to fit in there, the text goes over the section. how can i make sure that doesnt happen?

Comment: i already found the answer to my last question :), but im still looking for the header thing.

Comment: Here you go! http://jsfiddle.net/7k9vhk4r/2/ I made a new class with all the flexbox properties needed (all browsers included). Also, i added word-wrap: break-word; to <aside> so the words will stay in them. I'm not sure if this is how you fixed, but it's the most elegant solution for sure! If this helped a lot, would you mind selecting it as the accepted answer and giving it a positive rating too? Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, this is such a huge help! I selected your answer as the accepted answer. I cant give out rating yet though, need more rep for that :( .

Answer (score 1):

I just changed this:

- added `margin:0` to body
- Change `.main` rules to :

  ```
  /*width: 100%;*/
  margin: 200px 200px 0;
  height: 2000px; /* to make it big */
  /*left: ;*/
  ```

See the demo FULL PAGE

```css
body {

  background-image: url("background.jpg");
  margin:0;
}

div {

  margin: 0px;

}

.menu {

  background-color: lightgray;

  color: black;

  width: 200px;

  height: 100%;

  top: 200px;

  right: 0;

  text-align: center;

  position: fixed;

}

.contact {

  background-color: lightgray;

  color: black;

  width: 200px;

  height: 100%;

  top: 200px;

  left: 0;

  text-align: center;

  position: fixed;

}

.upper {

  background-color: black;

  width: 100%;

  height: 200px;

  position: fixed;

  top: 0px;

  left: 0px;

}

.main {

  background-color: green;

  /*width: 100%;*/

  margin: 200px 200px 0;

  height: 2000px;

  /*left: ;*/

}

.paragraph {

  background-color: red;

  width: 100%;

  height: 50vh;

}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>

<div class="contact"></div>

<div class="upper"></div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="paragraph"></div>
  <div class="paragraph"></div>
  <div class="paragraph"></div>
  <div class="paragraph"></div>
</div>
```